# Driving damaged car in France

Tags: driving, france

I am thinking about buying a car which I plan to drive around the French-Swiss border, maybe around Italy too. However, the car I found has quite visible damage from something which might look as a car crash (rear door is damaged quite badly, but it doesn't affect its functionality).

Can this create any issues (e.g. making police suspicious)?

Comment: I think this shold go to travel.stackexchange.com

Comment: Take a picture of the damage, with some way it could be dated, to show authorities to prove that it didn't happen recently, if you are suspected of hit and run.

Comment: Under what regulation are you asking about? Where are you buying this car? Could you be more precise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the car has a clean record and you bought it legally from the seller who had the right to sell it then you will be fine. Just retain all documentation.